# How do I set an @State variable programmatically in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a control that sets an `@State` variable to keep track of the selected tabs in a custom tab View. I can set the `@State` variable in code by setting the following:

```
@State var selectedTab: Int = 1
```

How do I set the initial value programmatically so that I can change the selected tab when the view is created?

I have tried the following:

1:

```
@State var selectedTab: Int = (parameter == true ? 1 : 2)
```

2:

```
init(default: Int) {
    self.$selectedTab = default
}
```

Comment: Have the same problem.

Comment: You are not supposed to initialize @State variables from data you pass down through the initializer; since the model is maintained outside of the view, there is no guarantee that the value will really be used. 

See my answer.

Comment: You should use a Binding to provide access to state that isn't local to your view.

Comment: Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58137096/7106170

Answer (score -7, accepted):

This was so simple to solve once I discovered the answer!

You simply remove the initial value from the initialization by changing the declaration from:

```
@State var selectedTab: Int = 1
```

to:

```
@State var selectedTab: Int
```

and then the selectedTab variable automatically becomes a parameter in the instantiation statement. So the initialization would be:

```
TabBarContentView(selectedTab: 2)
```

Its that simple!!!!!

Comment: This is not working if you have to write your own init.

Answer (score 35):

Example of how I set initial state values in one of my views:

```
struct TodoListEdit: View {
    var todoList: TodoList
    @State var title = ""
    @State var color = "None"

    init(todoList: TodoList) {
        self.todoList = todoList
        self._title = State(initialValue: todoList.title ?? "")
        self._color = State(initialValue: todoList.color ?? "None")
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

Joe Groff: "`@State` variables in SwiftUI should not be initialized from data you pass down through the initializer. The correct thing to do is to set your initial state values inline:"

`@State var selectedTab: Int = 1`

You should use a Binding to provide access to state that isn't local to your view.

`@Binding var selectedTab: Int`

Then you can initialise it from init and you can still pass it to child views.

Source: https://forums.swift.org/t/state-messing-with-initializer-flow/25276/3

Comment: But what if you have two cases, one where you want to pass data from a preceding view and another where you want to initialize with default data values (ie a creation/edit page)?

Comment: This discussion provides better context as to the mechanics of why @State variables should not be initialized as mentioned: https://forums.swift.org/t/assignment-to-state-var-in-init-doesnt-do-anything-but-the-compiler-gened-one-works/35235

Comment: Where do you data structure adaptation? I need to convert an array of enums to a set of strings so I can pass it to List so the user can select one or more items. The best way to do this would be to use the passed in array.  So I can't really agree that this is the correct policy.