# SwiftUI Documentation for @State property wrapper

Tags: swift, swiftui

I recently ran into an issue where I had to init an `@State` variable in my init method. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56691630/swiftui-state-var-initialization-issue/58137096#comment105955214_58137096) post helped me figure that out.

What I realized was that this is the way to do it:

```
@State var fullText: String // No default value of ""

init(letter: String) {
    _fullText = State(initialValue: list[letter]!)
}
```

I understand that `@State` is a property wrapper, and I read the documentation on property wrappers. And from other [reading](https://forums.swift.org/t/why-i-can-mutate-state-var-how-does-state-property-wrapper-work-inside/27209/2) I discovered under the hood this code:

```
@State private var flag = false
```

is translated into this code:

```
private var _flag: State<Bool> = State(initialValue: false)
private var $flag: Binding<Bool> { return _flag.projectedValue }
private var flag: Bool {
    get { return _flag.wrappedValue }
    nonmutating set { _flag.wrappedValue = newValue }
}
```

My question is where is it documented that `_variableName` is created from the wrapped property method and I can redefine it? How is a SwiftUI developer supposed to know that from Apple's docs? I'm trying to find what I'm assuming is Documentation I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As property wrappers were a *Swift Evolution* proposal and were developed as part of Swift's open source philosophy, we can find the best documentation directly in the [Proposal SE-0258 document](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0258-property-wrappers.md). 
This describes the rationale behind the `@propertyWrapper` design, and the *exact* specification to how they are implemented (including the definitions of *wrapped values* and *projected values*).

Sections that may help in your understanding:

> [§](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0258-property-wrappers.md#proposed-solution) A property wrapper type provides the storage for a property that uses it as a wrapper. The `wrappedValue` property of the wrapper type provides the actual implementation of the wrapper, while the (optional) `init(wrappedValue:)` enables initialization of the storage from a value of the property's type.
>
> The use of the prefix `_` for the synthesized storage property name is deliberate: it provides a predictable name for the synthesized storage property that fits established conventions for private stored properties.
>
> [...]
>
> [§](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0258-property-wrappers.md#projections) A property wrapper type can choose to provide a projection property (e.g., `$foo`) to expose more API for each wrapped property by defining a `projectedValue` property.
>   As with the `wrappedValue` property and `init(wrappedValue:)`, the `projectedValue` property must have the same access level as its property wrapper type.

As property wrappers are new to Swift as a whole, documentation is still lacking on Apple's side in my opinion, especially when it comes to SwiftUI.
However, there are only a handful of property wrappers we really have to know about (`@State`, `@Binding`, `@EnvironmentObject`, `@ObservedObject`, `@Published`) to fully utilise SwiftUI; all other aspects of SwiftUI (such as `View` types) are pretty well documented in Apple's Developer docs.

Additionally, articles shared in the Swift community ([example](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/property-wrappers-in-swift/)) can help you to get a grasp on where you might want to implement property wrappers yourself!