# Custom SwiftUI view with a two-way binding

Tags: ios, swiftui, combine

I'm struggling to implement a custom view which can take Binding as an argument and implement two-way updates of that value.

So basically I'm implementing my custom slider and want its initializer to be like this:

`MySlider(value: <Binding<Float>)`

---

What I'm struggling with:

1. How do I subscribe to remote updates of the binding value so that I can update the view's state?
2. Is there any nice way to bind a Binding with @State property?

---

Here's my current implementation so far which is not perfect.

```
struct MySlider: View {

    @Binding var selection: Float?
    @State private var selectedValue: Float?

    init(selection: Binding<Float?>) {
        self._selection = selection

        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/58137096
        _selectedValue = State(wrappedValue: selection.wrappedValue)
    }

    var body: some View {
         HStack(spacing: 3) {
             ForEach(someValues) { (v) in
                 Item(value: v,
                      isSelected: v == self.selection)
                     .onTapGesture {
                         // No idea how to do that other way so I don't have to set it twice
                         self.selection = v
                         self.selectedValue = v
                    }
             }
         }
    }
}
```

---

**Edit 1:**
I suppose my problem is that the underlying model object comes from Core Data and **wasn't owned by any SwiftUI view which would observe its changes.** The model object was owned by the UIKit ViewController and I was passing only a Binding to the SwiftUI view which is not enough.
My solution now is to pass the model object also to the SwiftUI View so that it can marked it as an `@ObservedObject`.

```
struct MySlider<T>: View where T: ObservableObject {

    @ObservedObject var object: T
    @Binding var selection: Float?

    var body: some View {
        return ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack(spacing: 3) {
                ForEach(values) { (v) in
                    Item(value: v,
                         isSelected: v == self.selection)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            self.selection = v
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear why do you need `selectedValue`? Why don't use bound `selection` directly?

Comment: Because updating `selection` doesn't trigger View update :< Views is updated when @State or @ObservedObject property is changed. It doesn't work with @Binding.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of `@Binding` is essentially a two-way connection to an underlying data item, such a a `@State` variable that's owned by *another* View. As stated by [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding):

> Use a binding to create a two-way connection between a view and its underlying model.

If it's a binding, SwiftUI will already update its views automatically if the value changes; so (in answer to your first question), you don't need to do any sort of subscriptions to update your custom view - that will happen automatically.

Similarly (regarding your second question), because the binding is the state from *another* view, you shouldn't be declaring it as a state for your view as well, and I also don't believe it's possible. State is something that should be a purely internal value to your view (Apple strongly recommend that all `@State` properties are declared `private`).

This all ties back to the 'Single Source of Truth' concept Apple stressed when unveiling SwiftUI: The parent view where that binding's already `@State` is what owns the information, so it's not something your view should also declare as a state.

For your code, I think all you need to do is take out that second state property, because it's not required. Just make sure the binding you pass is a `@State` property in whatever parent view owns your custom view, and pass it in using the `$` syntax to create that binding. [This article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/two-way-bindings-in-swiftui) covers the idea in more detail if you need.

```
struct MySlider: View {

    @Binding var selection: Float?

    init(selection: Binding<Float?>) {
        self._selection = selection
    }

    var body: some View {
         HStack(spacing: 3) {
             ForEach(someValues) { (v) in
                 Item(value: v, isSelected: v == self.selection)
                     .onTapGesture {
                         self.selection = v
                    }
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @TheNeil. What you said make sense but....it works only when we're operating with SwiftUI Views. What if the binding comes from the model? Like a property on NSManagedObject. I want to bind value of that property to the view.

Comment: I think you might want to make sure you have a ViewModel in between to handle that middle point - not ideal to have your Views talking directly to your Model like that. The binding should be passed by whatever view is responsible for creating and maintaining that custom view, rather than directly from the underlying data.

Comment: Did you remember to use `@ObservedObject` or `@EnvironmentObject` on whatever `View` property stores the `NSManagedObject`?

Comment: I didn't have the model object marked as the @ObservedObject because it wasn't owned by any SwiftUI view - it was coming from the UIKit ViewController. I've updated my original question ("edit 1") with my solution. Please let me know folks if you think this is the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

My answer might be a little late, but i stumbled across a similar problem. So here is how i solved it.

```
struct Item : Identifiable {
    var id : Int
    var isSelected : Bool
}

class MySliderObserver : ObservableObject {
   
   @Published var values = [Item]()
    
    init() {
        values.append(Item(id: 0, isSelected: false))
        values.append(Item(id: 1, isSelected: false))
        values.append(Item(id: 2, isSelected: false))
    }
    
    func toggleSelectForItem(id:Int) -> Void {
        guard let index = values.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == id }) else {
            return
        }

        var item = values[index]
        item.isSelected.toggle()
        values[index] = item
    }
}

struct MySlider: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var observer : MySliderObserver

    var body: some View {
        return ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            VStack(spacing: 3) {

                ForEach(self.observer.values) { v in
                    Text("Selected: \(v.isSelected ? "true" : "false")").onTapGesture {
                        self.observer.toggleSelectForItem(id: v.id)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and in the `SceneDelegate` you need to set an `EnvironmentObject` like:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        let contentView = MySlider()

        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView.environmentObject(MySliderObserver()))
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
```