# SwiftUI init doesn't work in a view struct

Tags: swiftui

I have this struct in my code:

```
struct TabsController: View {
   @State var selectedView = 1

  init(_ selectedView: Int) {
       self.selectedView = selectedView
  }

  var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedView){
        } 
  }   
}
```

And this one in another view:

```
self.viewControllerHolder?.present(style: .fullScreen) {
      TabsController(3)
 }
```

What i'm trying to do is to present the tabView with the third item selected. However, it doesn't work. I tried the following:

```
init(_ selectedView: Int) {
    self.selectedView = selectedView
    print("\(self.selectedView)")
    print("\(selectedView)")
}
```

And it showed 1 and 3, respectively, but the value still didn't change.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/58137096/1630618

Comment: @vacawama it did help, thanks a lot broski.