# @State autogenerated underscore-prefixed member variable

Tags: swift, swiftui, property-wrapper

I noticed via an Xcode autocompletion suggestion that `@State` seems to not only autogenerate a `$`-prefixed member for accessing the corresponding `Binding` (as is commonly known), but also a `_`-prefixed member, seemingly exposing the actual `State` wrapper.

This makes me wonder, what's the use case for it, and where is it mentioned in the docs?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found out it's actually due to how Swift (rather than SwiftUI) compiles `propertyWrapper`s under the hood.

From the [official swift docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Attributes.html) (under propertyWrapper):

> The compiler synthesizes storage for the instance of the wrapper type by prefixing the name of the wrapped property with an underscore (_)—for example, the wrapper for someProperty is stored as _someProperty. The synthesized storage for the wrapper has an access control level of private.

Here's what's happening each time you use a `propertyWrapper`:

[image]
*(From [better programming](https://medium.com/better-programming/the-inner-workings-of-state-properties-in-swiftui-8409ef39a7bd))*

As to its practical application in the context of SwiftUI, you can use it to initialize the `@State` variable, as described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58137096/442852) or [this blog post](https://nalexn.github.io/stranger-things-swiftui-state/).