# False error? `Variable used before being initialized` DURING initialization in init()

Tags: swift, struct, swiftui, initialization, init

Sorry for the non-sense example. Tried to simplify it, still don’t get what’s going on. The following gives me `Variable 'self.greeting' used before being initialized`:

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    @State var greeting: String
    var length = Measurement<UnitLength>(value: 5, unit: UnitLength.miles)
    init() {
        greeting = "Hello, World!" // Variable 'self.greeting' used before being initialized
    }
    var body: some View {
        Text(greeting)
    }
}
```

While this is working fine (`var length` differs; otherwise identical):

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    @State var greeting: String
    var length = 5 // now Int
    init() {
        greeting = "Hello, World!"
    }
    var body: some View {
        Text(greeting)
    }
}
```

Also, this is working (here I removed the `@State`):

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    var greeting: String // @State removed
    var length = Measurement<UnitLength>(value: 5, unit: UnitLength.miles)
    init() {
        greeting = "Hello, World!"
    }
    var body: some View {
        Text(greeting)
    }
}
```

- If the compiler wants me to initialize `greeting` **before** `init()` where would that be? `preinit()`?
- Why does it think `greeting` is being “used” uninitialized when actually I am initializing it here?
- Is there a different way to initialize @State vars? If so, why does it work when the unrelated var `length` is of `Int` rather than `Measurement`?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56691630/swiftui-state-var-initialization-issue). I have no idea why changing it to `var length = 5` works though. It shouldn't work in my opinion.

Comment: Apparently this is outdated. “It's not an issue nowadays to set a default value of the `@State` variables inside the `init` method. But you **MUST** just get rid of the default value which you gave to the state and it will work as desired” – 2022-02-12 https://stackoverflow.com/a/71092164/18195877 (so my example should work, as it does in the version with the Int-length)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code:

```
@State var greeting: String
```

Creates a backing variable behind the scenes:

```
let _greeting: State<String>
```

If you want to initialize it yourself in init(), you can do:

```
init() {
    _greeting = new State<String>(initialValue: "Hello, World!")
}
```

but since you have a constant, it is simpler to set it like this:

```
@State var greeting: String = "Hello, World!"
```

The 3rd variant works, because without @State there's no magic.

The 1st option doesn't work, because the code gets translated to:

```
init() {
    self._greeting.wrappedValue = "Hello, World!"
}
```

and `_greeting` is not initialized at this point (no initialValue is specified). Yes, the error is misleading.

I don't know why the 2nd version works. No initialValue is specified, and the String has no implicit default value. Maybe this is a new feature of iOS 15 SwiftUI that should work, but doesn't work in all cases due to some limitations?

P.S. There is something like "preinit": all properties that are assigned with some expressions like `length = Measurement<UnitLength>(...)` are run there before init, but there's no access to it, it is internal.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! Very interesting. According to Mojtaba Hosseini in https://stackoverflow.com/a/71092164/18195877 it should be possible to set the `@State var` in the `init` using it’s non-prefixed name. So, I would assume Apple added an incomplete feature which doesn’t work for structs/Views with `Measurements` (and more?) in it.