# Adding a property to a struct causes `Variable 'X' used before being initialized` errors elsewhere

Tags: swift, swiftui

The following code compiles without error:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Model {
    let foo: String
    // let bar: URL
}

struct ModelView: View {
    @State var model: Model

    init(model: Model) {
        self.model = model // error here when `Model.bar` is uncommented
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text(model.foo)
    }
}
```

However, uncommenting the `bar` property in `Model` leads to an error:

> Variable 'self.model' used before being initialized

in `ModellView.init()`.

Why does this happen? Adding other properties to `Model` does not cause this problem, e.g. changing the type of `bar` to `String`, `Int`, `CGFloat`, `NSLayoutConstraint` and many others works. OTOH, `Date` causes the same error as `URL`.

(using Swift 5.7 in Xcode 14.1)

Comment: See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71101108/5133585). The feature of initialising `State` without using the `_` prefix seems to be very buggy. Adding a `URL` in `ModelView` also breaks it.

Comment: My guess is that it breaks if there is anything from outside of the `Swift` module.

Comment: It should be `@Binding var model: Model` when you need write access to the state passed in, e.g. `TextField("", text: item.foo)`. But in your case it's simply `let model: Model` because you only need read access `Text(model.foo)`, body will be called when the `let` or `@Binding var` changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `@State` is a property wrapper, you should do that:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Model {
    let foo: String
     let bar: URL
}

struct ModelView: View {
    @State var model: Model

    init(model: Model) {
        _model = State(initialValue: model)
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text(model.foo)
    }
}
```