# Cannot use instance member 'service' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, mapkit

Im trying to get longitude and latitude from struct gService and set it on a Map.
But can't initialize `@State var region`, because of error "Cannot use instance member 'service' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available" on `service.latitude` and `service.longitude`

```
struct DetailCardView: View {

let service: gService

@State var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: service.latitude, longitude: service.longitude), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.0033, longitudeDelta: 0.0033))

var body: some View {

Map(coordinateRegion: $region, annotationItems: [MapPoint(coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: service.latitude, longitude: service.longitude))]) { location in
                    MapAnnotation(coordinate: location.coordinates) {
                        Circle()
                            .stroke(.red, lineWidth: 3)
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                    }
                }
```

I googled this problem, but there were different cases.

Comment: You need to create an initialiser on your `DetailCardView` and set your  state in that. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56691630/swiftui-state-var-initialization-issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, what the compiler is saying is that "I'm still creating the instance of your `DetailCardView`, I don't know yet what is the value of `service` so I can't use it in the `region`".

The solution is to pass the `service` to a constant that will be used to initialise **both** properties. You need to create an initializer for your View where you pass this constant.

Here's how it looks:

```
let service: gService


// Rather than service.longitude and service.latitude, use a dummy value, like 0.0
// Recommended this var to be private
@State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.0033, longitudeDelta: 0.0033))

// Here's your initializer
init(service: gService) {
    self.service = service      // Use service to initialise self.service

    // Use service - and NOT self.service - to initialise region
    region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: service.latitude, longitude: service.longitude), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.0033, longitudeDelta: 0.0033))
}

var body: some View {
...    // The rest of your code
```

Another method you can try is to drop the `init()` and set the `region` when the view appears, like this:

```
let service: gService


// Rather than service.longitude and service.latitude, use a dummy value, like 0.0
// Recommended this var to be private
@State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.0033, longitudeDelta: 0.0033))

var body: some View {
    Map(coordinateRegion: $region, annotationItems: [MapPoint(coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: service.latitude, longitude: service.longitude))]) { location in
                    MapAnnotation(coordinate: location.coordinates) {
                        Circle()
                            .stroke(.red, lineWidth: 3)
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                    }
        .onAppear {
            region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: service.latitude, longitude: service.longitude), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.0033, longitudeDelta: 0.0033))
        }
                }
```