# SwiftUI: preview doesn't display content in list

Tags: swiftui

I have created a very simple test in SwiftUI:

**Pokemon**

```
struct Pokemon: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}
```

**PokemonList**

```
struct PokemonList: View {
    @State private var pokemonList: [Pokemon] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        List(pokemonList) {
            PokemonRow(pokemon: $0)
        }
        .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                // Here I fill Pokemon list from API
            }
        }
    }
    
    init(_ pokemonList: [Pokemon] = []) {
        self.pokemonList = pokemonList
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct PokemonList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PokemonList([
            Pokemon(id: 1, name: "Bulbasaur"),
            Pokemon(id: 25, name: "Pikachu"),
            Pokemon(id: 150, name: "Mewtwo")
        ])
    }
}
#endif
```

**PokemonRow**

```
struct PokemonRow: View {
    var pokemon: Pokemon
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center) {
            Text("#\(pokemon.id)")    
            Text(pokemon.name)
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(height: 50)
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct PokemonRow_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PokemonRow(pokemon: Pokemon(id: 25, name: "Pikachu"))
    }
}
#endif
```

The `PokemonRow` preview works fine, and the API call too (the list is correctly filled after the view appears), but for some reason the `PokemonList` preview always displays empty content. Why is that?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Try using `.task {...}` instead of `.onAppear {...}`, and call an `async` function to download the Pokemon objects. Update the `@State var` inside that closure; there's no need to use a delay like `asyncAfter`.

Answer (score 0):

```
init(_ pokemonList: [Pokemon] = []) {
    self._pokemonList = State(initialValue: pokemonList) // << @State init
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to explain more about how this solves the problem, something like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56691630/swiftui-state-var-initialization-issue)