# Adding MapUserTrackingMode causes issues with initialization

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the following code that I've just added tracking mode to.

```swift
struct LocationInfoView: View {

  @State var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D
  @State private var mapRegion: MKCoordinateRegion
  @State private var trackingMode = MapUserTrackingMode.follow
  let markers: [Marker]

  init(location: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    self.location = location
    mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.00625, longitudeDelta: 0.00625))
    markers = [Marker(location: MapPin(coordinate: location))]
  }

  var body: some View {
    Map(
      coordinateRegion: $mapRegion,
      showsUserLocation: true,
      userTrackingMode: $trackingMode,
      annotationItems: markers) { marker in
        marker.location
      }
      .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
  }
}

struct Marker: Identifiable {
  let id = UUID()
  var location: MapPin
}
```

The moment I add the MapUserTrackingMode I get `Variable 'self.location' used before being initialized` and `Variable 'self.mapRegion' used before being initialized` errors. I don't understand why adding the tracking mode causes an issue with initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're getting isn't particularly helpful and it's made more confusing by the fact that what you were doing before the addition of `trackingMode` shouldn't have really worked in the first place.

The issue is that if you're going to initialize `@State` variables in a `View` init, you must use the `_myVar = State(...)` syntax:

```
@State var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D
@State private var mapRegion: MKCoordinateRegion
@State private var trackingMode = MapUserTrackingMode.follow
let markers: [Marker]

init(location: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
  _location = State(initialValue: location)
  _mapRegion = State(initialValue: MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.00625, longitudeDelta: 0.00625)))
  markers = [Marker(location: MapPin(coordinate: location))]
}
```

See related: [SwiftUI @State var initialization issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56691630/swiftui-state-var-initialization-issue)

Comment: This works thank you and thank you for including that link also. Helpful to know about state initialization.