# Variable used before being initialized with an EnvironmentObject in SwiftUI

Tags: variables, swiftui, init

I'am using an init to initialize my variable groupManager from the environmentObject objCOurse.

But Xcode tells me Variable 'self.groupeManager' used before being initialized

Where is the mistake ?

```
struct DepartsSimultanesView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var objCourse : CourseActuelle
    @State var selectedParcoursIndexArray : [Int] = []
    @State var groupeManager : GroupeManager
    
    init(groupeManager : GroupeManager) {
        self.groupeManager = GroupeManager(courseId: objCourse.id!) // Variable 'self.groupeManager' used before being initialized
        for _ in (0 ..< groupeManager.groupeList.count) {
            self.selectedParcoursIndexArray.append(0)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI @State var initialization issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56691630/swiftui-state-var-initialization-issue)

Comment: supposedly Xcode 14 you can do this, but it doesn't work for me either (and can't find anyone else talking about it except sarunw) https://sarunw.com/posts/state-variable-initialization/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @vadian comments, here what is working for me :

```
 init(groupeManager : GroupeManager, objCourse : CourseActuelle) {
        _groupeManager = State(initialValue: GroupeManager(courseId: objCourse.id!))
        var Varray : [Int] = []
        for _ in (0 ..< groupeManager.groupeList.count) {
            Varray.append(0)
        }
        _selectedParcoursIndexArray = State(initialValue: Varray)
        print(selectedParcoursIndexArray)
    }
```