# @Bindning wrapper gives an error while using with init()

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am creating a special `Textfield` for macOS. I want to create my own initializer, for special naming. But when I create that initializer with `@Binding` it gives two errors.

I don't now why it gives this initialization error. It's being clearly initialized there. Here is my code:

```
struct MacOSTextField: View{
    @Binding var text: String
    var displayText: String
    var body: some View{
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 0.4)
            .overlay {
                TextField(displayText, text: $text)
            }
    }
    init(text: String, displayText: String) {
        self.displayText = displayText
        self.text = text << Error: 'self' used before all stored properties are initialized
    } << Error: Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties
}
```

It does not work when I remove `self.text = text` or change the place of it. Here is the code when `self.text = text` is removed:

```swift
struct MacOSTextField: View{
    @Binding var text: String
    var displayText: String
    var body: some View{
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 0.4)
            .overlay {
                TextField(displayText, text: $text)
            }
    }
    init(text: String, displayText: String) {
        self.displayText = displayText
        self.text = text
    } << Error: Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: A `Binding` is for two-way communication. You're just passing in a `String`. At the least, you need to pass in a `Binding`. Then, you can assign it in `init` using a technique similar to what's necessary for `@State`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56691630/swiftui-state-var-initialization-issue

Comment: Xcode auto-filled the code for me so, I continued the code with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `text` is a `@Binding`, you need to pass it as such to the `init`:

```
init(
    text: Binding<String>, // <-- passing it to the init
    displayText: String
) {
        self.displayText = displayText
        self._text = text // <-- assigning value to it. Notice the "_"
    }
```

This of course assumes that the view that holds this view will have something like:

```
struct ParentView: View {
    
    @State var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        MacOSTextField(
            text: $text, // <-- passing a binded variable. Notice the "$" 
            displayText: "Something"
        )
```

Also note that what you call `displayText` is actually a placeholder text. the "displayed text" will be in the `text` binded variable