# "Variable 'self.__' used before being initialized" error on SwiftUI for Date but not for String

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have two very identical simple SwiftUI view. Why the one with `Date` fails? I cannot understand.

I tried some other types.

Fail: `Date`, `(Int, Date)`, `Any`, `struct MyStruct {let string: String; let date: Date}`

Not fail: `String`, `Int`, `[Date]`, `NSNumber`, `struct MyStruct {let string: String}`

```
struct StringDemoView: View {
    @State var stateValue: String
    
    init(initialValue: String) {
        stateValue = initialValue
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        EmptyView()
    }
}


struct DateDemoView: View {
    @State var stateValue: Date
    
    init(initialValue: Date) {
        stateValue = initialValue //<-- Variable 'self.stateValue' used before being initialized
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        EmptyView()
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be using the `State(initialValue:)` initializer. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56691630/swiftui-state-var-initialization-issue

Comment: @jnpdx Yes it solves the error. But what I am asking is why String one works, but not Date one.

Comment: Probably an anomaly with the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is wrong anyway.

A `@State` struct member must be initialized this way

```
struct DateDemoView: View {
    @State private var stateValue: Date 

    init(initialValue: Date) {
        _stateValue = State(wrappedValue: initialValue) // or State(initialValue:
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        EmptyView()
    }
}
```

The question is actually irrelevant because the *simple* initialization doesn't work. But my guess is that `String` and `Int` are part of the Swift Language itself while `Date` is part of the `Foundation` framework bridging `NSDate`. On the other hand `NSNumber` brakes this *rule*….

It's not related to the issue but it's highly recommended to declare `@State` members private.

Comment: Yes it solves the error. But what I am asking is why String one works, but not Date one. How can "wrong" syntax can work for most of the types I tried?