# SwiftUI Cancellable? in View breaks initializer

Tags: swift, swiftui

Why is this code incorrect when I add the timer to the view:

```
class Dummy {
    
}

struct DemoView: View {
    
    @State var timer: Cancellable? = nil
    
    @State var dummy: Dummy
    
    
    init(dummy_in: Dummy) {
        dummy = dummy_in //>>> ERROR: Variable 'self.dummy' used before being initialized
        
        // SOME MORE LOGIC HERE
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Dummy")
    }
    
}
```

It works fine until I add the timer which is initialized with nil as it is nullable.

This is very unintuitive behavior

EDIT: it does work when I change dummy to a @ObservedObject.
Would still like to understand what is happening here

Comment: I suspect this is likely an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you trying to do here, ultimately?

Comment: What i want to do, can also be done with @ObservedObject instead of _@State. The question is more for understanding what is happening here as i thought i understood how SwiftUI works. thus i see this more like a syntax clarification question

Comment: But okay here is what im trying to do:
1.) I have a Instance of a Class (Dummy in example) that i want to Modify by giving it to a Editor like View (DummyView in example)
2.) i need a Timer that frequently calls the Element to be edited to update its internal logic
3.) i want to give the element to the View via the init. 

i know this can be done with ObservedObject, but what if the given element is not Observable?

Comment: What's this "element" that you keep mentioning? Is it `Dummy`? if "element" is not an `Observable`, `ObservableObject`, or a struct, then you can't observe it, and views don't update when the element changes.

Comment: Yes Dummy is the element i want to modify, and in my actual usecase its observable. 
Still i would like to know why this is incorrect code as i frequently have problems with initializer and self reference

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56691630/swiftui-state-var-initialization-issue

Comment: @vadian does not explain why Cancellable? makes the difference here. its like some sort of magic happening in the background with Cancellable that references the class States

Comment: Nevertheless your way to initialize a `@State` property is wrong and the error goes away when you use the correct way `_dummy = State(wrappedValue: dummy_in)`.

Comment: okay that is an explanation im okay accepting, the syntax is a bit uggly ok. 
so the answer would be: asigning states directly is just some syntax magic to make the code clearer, but it breaks sometimes. in this case use _dummy = State...

Comment: No, there is only one case, *assigning states directly* is wrong, it doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255763/discussion-between-save-jeff-and-vadian).

Comment: @vadian: but it does work fine as long as you dont add the timer. also xcode auto-generates the init with direct assignment to the state. how can it be wrong then?

Answer (score 1):

Apple says about `State(wrappedValue value: Value)`

> You don’t call this initializer directly.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state/init(wrappedvalue:)

You can use

```
_dummy = State(initialValue: dummy_in)
```

Also, remember that `State` is meant to be a source of truth. It isn't meant to come from a parent. It handles the identity of a `View` and when a parent tries to give it a value there are more often than not more disconnects.

`State` should also always be marked `private` so the memberwise initializer isn't created.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state

`init` that do "work" are not a good idea with SwiftUI, SwiftUI can recreate a `View` at anytime, the timer is likely causing the `View` to be recreated.

Answer (score 0):

To pass data into a View it is `let` for ready only or `@Binding var` for read/write, eg

```
@Binding var dummy: Dummy
```

In either case `body` is called when the value is changed. Since it only works with value types `Dummy` must be changed to a struct:

```
struct Dummy {
    mutating func someLogic { }  
}
```

FYI for a timer use `TimelineView`