# SwiftUI - How to setup a .tag for .tabItems build using ForEach

Tags: swift, swiftui, tabitem

In the following sample code, hope its not to long, I have difficulties to get it right. At first I did want to use a enum with associated values and actions, but choose a way that I did understand a little better.

In my current code, the .tag's are giving me a little headache, I did try several methods to get it right but to no a veal. The errors it shows is "No exact matches in reference to static method 'buildExpression'" on the line '.tag(item.tag)'and '.tabItem' line.

```
import SwiftUI

class SettingsTabItemManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tabItems: [SettingsTabItem] = []

    init() {
        createTabItems()
    }

    func createTabItems() {
        self.tabItems = [
             SettingsTabItem(
                label: "General",
                labelImage: "gear", 
                tag: "general", 
                action: {}, 
                view: GeneralSettingsView(), 
                description: "The general settings tabItem"),
                         
             SettingsTabItem(
                label: "Network", 
                labelImage: "network", 
                tag: "network", 
                action: {}, 
                view: NetworkSettingsView(), 
                description: "The network settings tabItem"),
                         
             SettingsTabItem(
                label: "Advanced", 
                labelImage: "star", 
                tag: "advanced", 
                action: {}, 
                view: AdvancedSettingsView(), 
                description: "The advanced settings tabItem")
        ]
    }
}

struct SettingsTabItem {
    var id : UUID = UUID()
    var label: String
    var labelImage: String
    var tag: String // or enum Tabs
    var action: () -> Void
    var view: any View
    var description: String
}

struct SettingsView: View {
    @StateObject private var tabItemManager = SettingsTabItemManager()
    @State private var selectedTab: String?

    init() {
        _selectedTab = State(initialValue: tabItemManager.tabItems.first?.tag)
    }


    @State var tapped = false

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Group {
                ForEach(tabItemManager.tabItems, id: \.id) { item in
                    item.view
                        .tabItem {
                            Label(item.label, systemImage: item.labelImage)
                        }
                        .tag(item.tag) // I did try also ( .tag(item.tag.hashValue) )
                }
                .onTapGesture {
                    tapped.toggle()
                    //  more is coming
                }
            }
            .padding(20)
            .frame(width: 375, height: 150)
        }
    }
}

struct GeneralSettingsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("GeneralSettingsView")
    }
}

struct NetworkSettingsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("NetworkSettingsView")
    }
}

struct AdvancedSettingsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("AdvancedSettingsView")
    }
}
```

What do I overlook here? Maybe I should do it different but this is what I came up with. Maybe I should use some sort of viewbuilder, but don't know that how to.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note AFAIK, you should not hold on to `View`, like `var view: any View`.  Views are for use by themselves or in other `View`, not in your  SettingsTabItem or in class SettingsTabItemManager. I suggest you restructure your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have a `View` in your `SettingsTabItem`.

```
var view: any View // remove this!
```

I assume you want to be able to change the tabs in the tab view dynamically, and that's why you created the `SettingsTabItem` struct. So the array of `SettingsTabItem`s represents *state*, and views in SwiftUI are a function of state.

You should write a function that, given a `SettingsTabItem`, return some `View`. For example, in the simple case you showed here:

```
@ViewBuilder
func tabView(forTabItem tabItem: SettingsTabItem) -> some View {
    switch tabItem.tag { // also consider using an enum for the tag
    case "general":
        GeneralSettingsView()
    case "network":
        NetworkSettingsView()
    case "advanced":
        AdvancedSettingsView()
    default:
        EmptyView()
    }
}
```

You can expand this function to do whatever things you need to do, to figure out what the `View` corresponding to a given `SettingsTabItem` should be. You might need to add more properties to `SettingsTabItem` in your real scenario.

Notice that I avoided the problem of the views all having different types by using `@ViewBuilder`, and this could only be done if the view is written as a function of state. You tried to use `any View` to solve this problem, and that caused the error.

Then you can just call this function in `ForEach`:

```
tabView(forTabItem: item)
    .tabItem {
        Label(item.label, systemImage: item.labelImage)
    }
    .tag(item.tag)
```

Side note: The way you initialise `selectedTab` is an an anti pattern. ([See also the many answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56691630/5133585)) I would suggest initialising `selectedTab` to some dummy value first, then assign it the first tab's tag in `onAppear`, and/or every time the tab items do not contain an item with the tag `selectedTab` (you can detect this with `onChange`).