# SwiftUI Maps - Cannot use instance member within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit

I'm trying to use MapKit's Map with SwiftUI and dynamic latitude/longitude values that are passed into the view by the parent view on the navigation stack. All the MapKit documentation for Swift indicates you need to use @State with `MKCoordinateRegion` but always uses it with constant latitude/longitude values.

```swift
struct PlaceDetail: View {
    let place: Place
    
    @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: place.latitude, longitude: place.longitude),
        latitudinalMeters: 750,
        longitudinalMeters: 750
    )
    
    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: region)
    }
}
```

I want to be able to use this dynamically with the `latitude`/`longitude` values provided by the `place` object passed in by the parent view. The above code results in an compiler errors:

`Cannot use instance member 'place' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available`

What's the cleanest/most updated way to get this view to compile and work as expected?

---

Edit: I have tried using an initializer but end up with another error relating to assigning against state:

```
struct PlaceDetail: View {
    let place: Place
    
    @State var region: MKCoordinateRegion
    
    init(place: Place) {
        self.place = place
        
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(
            center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: place.latitude, longitude: place.longitude),
            latitudinalMeters: 750,
            longitudinalMeters: 750
        )
        
        self.region = State(initialValue: region)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $region)
    }
}
```

Results in:

`Cannot assign value of type 'State<MKCoordinateRegion>' to type 'MKCoordinateRegion'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set an @State variable programmatically in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56591837/how-do-i-set-an-state-variable-programmatically-in-swiftui)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was close in the final edit, but I needed to assign the value `_region` - not the prefixed underscore. It looks like this is a private setter which is why you need to wrap the value in `State`. And not forget to use the `$` prefix to use the instance variable in the view.

```swift
struct PlaceDetail: View {
    let place: Place
    
    @State var region: MKCoordinateRegion
    
    init(place: Place) {
        self.place = place
        
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(
            center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: place.latitude, longitude: place.longitude),
            latitudinalMeters: 750,
            longitudinalMeters: 750
        )
        
        self._region = State(initialValue: region)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $region)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this. It was extremely helpful!